# issue in translating a wordpress them

Tags: translation

im working on translating a wordpress theme, i have translate all the language files even the related plugins files but then when i apply on my theme some words are translated and some not, this photo explian it all, as you can see some words still in english even i'm sure i have translate it in the language file and i have also check the directory and the line number of this words
[image]
here is a screenshot of the plugin language folder
[image]
and this is for theme language folder

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include some example code demonstrating a section with a translation that works and one that doesn't? Keep in mind your strings must perfectly match, capitalisation and all, they must be perfectly identical

Comment: what is the language of your admin area?

Comment: i think i have figure out what is the problem, there is a language file in plugins and language file in the theme, the language file in theme works really fine, but the plugins language file dont work and i dont know why